# SMS send from within an app seem impossible to detect?

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I have just created a cool app that work with SMS. I would like to say to my users: don't worrry, my app send SMS but you can track them in your favourite SMS application.

I don't want them to be afraid that I will overload their monthly fees.

So, the way I send SMS is very simple:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, position, pi, null);
```

And that is very fine.

Unfortunately, all sent SMS does not appear in any SMS application, so user doesn't know that a SMS has been send.

Yes, of course, I could create a list in my application that shows send SMS, but the user won't trust me.

So I am very afraid that SMS send within app are totally invisible and there is no way to track them from the end user side.

Comment: But you've allready figured out how to send an SMS without notifying the user. So any text in the list has the same value as a text in any list you would make yourself, which -- as you say -- the user won't trust. So problem is not really solvable. If the user doesn't trust you, he/she doesn't. That's about it :(

Comment: @Nanne, that's exactly why I don't understand that the SMS app is not able to get the intent of the send SMS. The SMS app is really a better trusted source than my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any other solutions, the answer seem to be "NO, there is no solutions".

That's a big security issue, in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You could not use sms permission in your application, and instead send an sms via an intent.  This will bring up the messaging app with the sms destination and body pre-filled so the user just pushes send.

However if you send a lot of messages, this probably is asking too much.  And users may get confused - you would have to show a screen in your application to the effect of 'This program needs to send an SMS - please press "continue" and then "send" when the messaging application opens'

Comment: I forgot to mention: my app is like a SMS server. You send a question to the device, like "where are you" and the app reply immediatly. The user cannot be involved in the process with a button.